# Chrome (Windows) changes font family when special characters are used

Tags: html, css, fonts

My problem can be best described by attaching these two screenshots: [[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1GGR.jpg) [[2]](http://imgur.com/1Mg0Yvp)

In the second image, notice the "Continue Reading" link is rendered in sans-serif (?), and in the first image the problem is clear.

Basically, **this only happens in Chrome on Windows**.

So it seems like any line containing an HTML special character will have its font-family affected, and rendered in some sort of default-type fonts. I realize these custom characters may not be present in my first-choice font, but why are other characters affected as well? How can I remedy this?

If it's of any help, here's a link to [my website](http://thetypist.com). I'm using Ideal Sans SSm by H&FJ.

**edit**: It seems that my question isn't that clear after all. If you look at image [[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1GGR.jpg), you can see how Chrome renders my fonts after an HTML character has been used. This is how the HTML looks like:

`Especially if you&#8217;re new to OS X, this is the very first app you want to have. Holding &#8984; for a bit longer presents you with a list of active shortcuts, both global and app-specific ones. CheatSheet is also useful for existing Mac users looking to expand their shortcut vocabulary for extra effectiveness.`

As seen in image [[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1GGR.jpg), when this code is inserted, a different font is rendered.

Note: on my live website I currently have `span` tags around the special characters (that's a ⌘, by the way) in order for visitors not to suffer from this. This can actually help us with a direction towards the answer: Why is it that when the special character (any special HTML character) is wrapped in `span` tags, it and only it is affected by this, but when it's wrapped in `span` tags, the whole line is affected.

Comment: looks fine on my chrome, I am on a mac book pro

Comment: The problem is only on Windows machines. I edited the title.

Comment: You need include actual code into the question, for reproducing the issue. Now the question is formulated so that it becomes rather incomprehensible after you have fixed your live site.

Comment: Actually, the question is incomprehensible even now. The page mentioned does not have content like those in the screenshot. You need show HTML and CSS code (preferably a minimal case) that actually produces the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What I fixed doesn't really affect the problem I have as it's still the case with image #2, and I explain what happens in image #1 in my update.

Comment: Not reproducible with the given text in Chrome 31 on Win 7. You should focus on presenting a complete example that actually produces the effect. This includes CSS (you apparently have some CSS for setting font family, to begin with).

Comment: I can't see the problem happening either, but my guess is that the browser is unwilling to change the font face for just one character; maybe it presumes that more similar characters will be in the same sentence, so it keeps the whole sentence in that font, for consistency reasons. That said, I don't know why it would change the font to one that doesn't contain the offending character either!

Comment: But if you're using a webfont anyway, why not choose one that includes the ⌘ to begin with? Then you wouldn't have the problem.